# Change the size of a dialog box for a firefox extension?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xul

How do I change the size of a dialog box for a firefox extenion?

In javascript onload, I know how to call "window.sizeToContent()" for it to guess what the size should be, but does anyone know how I can change the window width and height specifically?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're creating it with `window.openDialog` and passing it the URL of a XUL file, then you can just put it in the XUL file:

```
<?xml yadda yadda yadda>
<dialog xmlns="blah blah blah"
        width="100"
        height="100"
>
   ...
</dialog>
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that setting the width and height as XUL attributes affects the outer width and height of the window. If you want to set the inner width and height then the easiest way is via the style attribute i.e. `<dialog style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">`

Other ways of setting the width and height include passing features to `openDialog`, calling `resizeTo` or setting `outerWidth`, `outerHeight`, `innerWidth` or `innerHeight` in script.